# C++ instantiate new class as inherited class type

Tags: c++

So let's say I have an abstract class Car, from which the classes Ford and Mazda are derived.

```cpp
class Car{
public:
    float fuel_capacity = 0;
    virtual float get_fuel_capacity();
    virtual void set_fuel_consumption(float x);
}
```

```cpp
class Ford : public Car
{
public:
    Ford();
    float get_fuel_capacity() {return fuel_capacity}
    void set_fuel_capacity(float x) {fuel_capacity = x};
};
```

```cpp
class Mazda: public Car{
public:
    Mazda();
    float get_fuel_capacity() {return fuel_capacity}
    void set_fuel_capacity(float x) {fuel_capacity = x};
};
```

Using those classes I want to define a garage containing my cars:

```cpp
class Garage{
    stack<Car> cars;
    void add_car(Car x){cars.push(x)}
    Car get_cars(){return cars;}
}
```

Now I thought that by requiring the abstract class in `add_car` I could pass any of the derived types, but it seems I cannot because `no suitable constructor exists to convert from "Ford *" to "Car"` pops up.

So there I  have it.
How can I call something like:

```cpp
Garage g;
g.add_car(new Ford());
g.add_car(new Mazda());
```

*I dont even know how to search for this on google :(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in this case is not inheritance but the fact that you pass a pointer as a parameter to a method where a value is requested.

You should change your `Garage` class to solve this by doing the following:

```
class Garage {
    stack<Car*> cars;
    void add_car(Car* x) { cars.push(); }
}
```

Also note that your `get_car` won't compile, because your return type does not match the thing that you actually return. You should change the return type to something like `const stack<Car*>&`.

But as *idclev463035818* stated: You seem to lack some basics.
Reading C++ compiler errors may be hard at times, but this is something that should be so basic that when the compiler tells you that there is an issue in that line, you simply look at the line and see your mistake. This is a kind of issue that could be resolved by reading a book (or something similar) on C++ instead of asking SO questions.

Comment: you dont have to give credits for my comments, and you should not cite me incorrect/incomplete. "no offense, but you seem to lack some basics" vs "You lack basics" is a small but substantial difference